# Import multi-band TIFF in R

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff, stack

I am trying to import a TIFF file that contains 2 bands. When using the following code in R, it seems only the first band is being recognised.

```
S1<-"my/path/"
S1<-list.files(S1, full.names = TRUE, pattern="tif$")
S1<-lapply(1:length(S1), function (x) {raster(S1[x])})
```

S1 being at this point:

```
> S1
[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  2  bands)
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /shared/Training/EARSEL0918_UrbanClassification_Germany/Processing/Coherence__20180412_20180424_TC.tif 
names       : Coherence__20180412_20180424_TC
```

My objective is to create a raster stack containing both layers (for further processing in R). If I run

```
S1<-stack(S1)

> S1
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 3865, 6899, 26664635, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 14.83, 14.83  (x, y)
extent      : 361363.5, 463675.7, 5760647, 5817965  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : Coherence__20180412_20180424_TC
```

Comment: Use brick() not raster stack(lapply(S1, brick)) - but do check the length of S1, make sure brick() gives two layers (it will "1  (of  2  bands)") but I'm seeing that S1 is length 1 here.

Comment: Do you mean a multi- **band** raster?

Comment: @Vince, yes exactly

Comment: @mdsumner, I have tried with brick but the same was happening

Comment: Can you confirm that `brick("/shared/Training/EARSEL0918_UrbanClassification_Germany/Processing/Coherence__20180412_20180424_TC.tif")`  has one or two layers?

Comment: To the band-edit mavens, in `raster` package in R multi-band manifests as multi-layer - so blithely changing this terminology without context isn't super helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you read a TIFF with `raster` like you have in your loop you'll only get one layer read:

```
> r = raster("./GcrfPicture.tif")
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  4  bands)
dimensions  : 720, 960, 691200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
```

The `1 (of 4 bands)` is telling you that the source had four bands but its only read one.

Use `stack` instead:

```
> s = stack("./GcrfPicture.tif")
> s
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 720, 960, 691200, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
```

Comment: Did not know `stack` could be use to import files in such way. It works, thank you

Comment: @GCGM, stack has iteration build in so, you can just pass it a vector of file names. If the rasters do not align, you can use quick=TRUE but, this is of limited utility for any type of analysis.

Comment: fwiw, `stack` is the same as `brick` in the multi-layer/band/channel distinction, just lazier and able to deal with more disparate inputs - it's not easy to characterize the difference and it does depend both on the formats used and the way you use them.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans you mean if the rasters *do* align ?

Comment: @mdsumner nope, you can create a stack with non-aligned rasters using this argument to bypass the check. In this way you can store rasters in a stack, rather than a list. However, if you try to use any raster functions (eg., calc, overlay) on the stack, as opposed to a single raster in the stack, you will receive an error.

Comment: I never considered that use-case!  You actually do that?  To me quick is for when you know they align, so raster doesn't have to check every one and ensure they are equal.